# Meteor killed by ubuntu while trying to "run Meteor" on a server

Tags: meteor, server

My goal is to follow "Deploying a Meteor app with Nginx from scratch" tutorial available [here](https://medium.com/@tomgoldenberg/deploying-a-meteor-app-with-nginx-from-scratch-1332b32e99a5#.b6jgwftgq)

After installing Meteor, Node, Forever and Git, do the npm install, I try to "run meteor" to see if it works.

After downloading meteor-tools, the process begins to extract meteor-tools... looks like it is hanging for a couple minutes and then stops without any warning.

So my guess is that something causes the extraction to quit, but i don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Meteor likes plenty of RAM. I would recommend using Phusion Passenger with nginx for Meteor, it's very easy to set up, and their tutorials/getting started is very good:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/

Comment: tks, i will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the exact reason. However, I got it working. I was using a DigitalOcean server (512Mb/20G). I tried with a big server (16G/160G) and it works.

So I guess my server Ram OR Disk capacity was too small.

Edit:
setting up smaller configuration, i noticed that the minimum for Meteor to work is: 2Gb of RAM and 40Gb Disk.

Comment: In development we have found that any machine with 4G of RAM struggles. With 16G mine flies, so your results are not surprising